# How to get pending Async task count in spring?

Tags: java, spring

In my spring application, I've an `Async` method like the following in myService:

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public void exportObject(String id) {
    System.out.println("exporting " + id);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("exported " + id);
}
```

Here is how I'm creating the `TaskExecutor` bean

```
@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(5);

    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}
```

Inside my `Controller` I'm calling the `Async` method like the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    myService.exportObject(i+"");
}
```

Now I want to get the total number of pending Async tasks that have been added to queues. How can I get this? I've tried the following in my controller class but the TaskExecutor have no method that serves this purpose.

```
@Autowire
private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

public int getPendingTaskCount(){
    // taskExecutor.getPendingTaskCount(); // ?
}
```

Comment: I wonder if that would be possible at all. When you count pending tasks you either have to block all other threads, so that they do not steal some task or other tasks are added while you count (and thus alter your number) or provide a *weak/approximate* of that number. Interesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* do:

```
long result = threadPoolTaskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor().getTaskCount() -
              threadPoolTaskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor().getCompletedTaskCount();
```

But that would be an approximate and each of those methods actually uses a ReentrantLock for locking.

Comment: Is there any other way without locking?

Comment: @Naya not really. the locking is done internally. Isn't this approximation enough for your case?

Comment: Yeah, that's enough. I'm going to use this. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Where in your example code did you use this solution? @Nayan